# Want to execute SET of Rspec TEST SUITE in parallel manner with different inputs using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I used fixtures which contain different configuration '.yml' files.

Which will load after execution and apply each '.yml' file to the common Rspec TEST SUITE.
Means once common Rspec TEST SUITE which will execute with different configuration parallely (at the same time).

I found lots of example for the Rspec TEST CASE parallel execution. But I want to execute a common Rspec TEST SUITE with the different configuration.